# Can I send a link to a specific position within a web page using Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to send a link to a paragraph in a web page that does not already have a link set for it, is there a way to do that in Chrome?

For instance, if there was a link, I could have used it, so for instance to the #top could be referenced like:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Roddenberry#top
```

But I want to add a scroll to or some other method of choosing where to scroll the browser's screen to.  I hope there is a chrome specific method of doing this, that would be good enough (it does not have to work in all browsers).

Comment: Just use the element`s ID.
In your example the user will be navigated to the element on wikipedia page that has id of 'top'

Comment: That totally works! for example - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Roddenberry#Early_life_and_career

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Petko Kostov said in the comments the solution is to simply use the documents already in place markup. (This has the limit that it may not work exactly as you like if the document does not have good markup.)

Step 1:
View source, or right-click on the page and click "Inspect". Then in the HTML look for an ID around where you want to link the user to. If one exists, you can use that by simply appending the id to the link.

From the question,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Roddenberry#top

will find an element with `id="top"`

A second example, on that same Wikipedia page, there is a section labeled 'Early life and career', examining the HTML around that section, we see:

```
<h2>
  <span class="mw-headline" id="Early_life_and_career">Early life and career</span>
  <span class="mw-editsection">
    <span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span>
      <a href="/w/index.php?title=Gene_Roddenberry&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1" title="Edit section: Early life and career">edit</a>
    <span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span>
  </span>
</h2>
```

You can see there is an `id` on the `span`, so we can use that to form this URL:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Roddenberry#Early_life_and_career

And that will scroll the user to that section on page load.

Answer (score 3):

Petko was right, in your code just select the element (by id or by text you are looking for) and scroll to it.

but i stumbled upon this question when i was trying to find a way to get such a link manually. there was some paragraph in a very long docu page i wanted to send to my colleague.

so if it helps someone, the latest chrome version has a way of doing so:

**select wanted text** -> **right mouse click** -> **copy link to highlight** -> **THATS IT**

see screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is very cool! interestingly it does not scroll the user to it, but it does highlight it. On some pages, this means the site adds additional UI (like some sights have 'share to' or other gadgets that show after you highlight some text and those are active on page load. Nice tip!

Comment: @nycynik now as of 2021-11-20 using Google Chrome (Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)) this does seem to scroll down to the highlighted text now. Try this in a new tab in Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751867/can-i-send-a-link-to-a-specific-position-within-a-web-page-using-chrome/68336076#:~:text=does%20not%20scroll%20the%20user%20to%20it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply right-click the element you want to link, and click on inspect element. Than you can see the ID or tag of that element. If itself doesn't has a tag or ID, you can use the tag or ID of the div it is in.

Then you just take the URL of the webpage, and attach # and behind the # the ID or Tag of the targeted element.